# how do I move files in bazel when building a cc_library?

Tags: c, build, dependencies, bazel

When building projects from source in bazel, the header files do not always end at the correct relative paths.

For example,  I'd like to build [expat](https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat) from source.
The main header that other software will use is `<expat.h>`.
However, the project has the source code in `expat/lib/expat.h`.

I can build the project successfully with:

```
cc_library(
    name = "expat",
    srcs = [
        "lib/xmlparse.c",
        "lib/xmlrole.c",
        "lib/xmltok.c",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "expat_config.h",
        "lib/ascii.h",
        "lib/asciitab.h",
        "lib/expat.h",
        "lib/expat_external.h",
        "lib/iasciitab.h",
        "lib/internal.h",
        "lib/latin1tab.h",
        "lib/nametab.h",
        "lib/siphash.h",
        "lib/utf8tab.h",
        "lib/xmlrole.h",
        "lib/xmltok.h",
        "lib/xmltok_impl.c",
        "lib/xmltok_impl.h",
        "lib/xmltok_ns.c",
    ],
    includes = [
        ".",
        "lib",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

but now other projects that try to link with `@expat//:expat` will be unable to find `<expat.h>`.  The correct inclusion would need to be `<expat/lib/expat.h>` which is not feasible to change in other software.

What's the best way to build the project as-is, but still ensure the header files are in the correct place for other projects that use them?  I'm wondering if I need to perform a cp somehow within skylark first before calling the `cc_library`, or if I can move the headers afterward.  I don't want to change the actual contents of the project (because I may not be hosting it or I want the mirror to remain consistent).  I'm not sure how I would write a rule to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by moving each file individually via separate rules.

First, I made a rule over `mv`:

```
def mv_file(name, file_from, file_to):

    native.genrule(
        name = name,
        srcs = [file_from],
        outs = [file_to],
        output_to_bindir = 1,
        cmd = "mv $< $@",
    )
```

Then in the BUILD file for the dependency I used it as follows:

```
mv_file("xmlparse_c","expat/lib/xmlparse.c","xmlparse.c")
mv_file("xmlrole_c","expat/lib/xmlrole.c","xmlrole.c")
mv_file("xmltok_c","expat/lib/xmltok.c","xmltok.c")
mv_file("ascii_h","expat/lib/ascii.h","ascii.h")
mv_file("asciitab_h","expat/lib/asciitab.h","asciitab.h")
mv_file("expat_h","expat/lib/expat.h","expat.h")
mv_file("expat_external_h","expat/lib/expat_external.h","expat_external.h")
mv_file("iasciitab_h","expat/lib/iasciitab.h","iasciitab.h")
mv_file("internal_h","expat/lib/internal.h","internal.h")
mv_file("latin1tab_h","expat/lib/latin1tab.h","latin1tab.h")
mv_file("nametab_h","expat/lib/nametab.h","nametab.h")
mv_file("siphash_h","expat/lib/siphash.h","siphash.h")
mv_file("utf8tab_h","expat/lib/utf8tab.h","utf8tab.h")
mv_file("xmlrole_h","expat/lib/xmlrole.h","xmlrole.h")
mv_file("xmltok_h","expat/lib/xmltok.h","xmltok.h")
mv_file("xmltok_impl_c","expat/lib/xmltok_impl.c","xmltok_impl.c")
mv_file("xmltok_impl_h","expat/lib/xmltok_impl.h","xmltok_impl.h")
mv_file("xmltok_ns_c","expat/lib/xmltok_ns.c","xmltok_ns.c")

cc_library(
    name = "expat",
    srcs = [
        "xmlparse.c",
        "xmlrole.c",
        "xmltok.c",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "expat/expat_config.h",
        "ascii.h",
        "asciitab.h",
        "expat.h",
        "expat_external.h",
        "iasciitab.h",
        "internal.h",
        "latin1tab.h",
        "nametab.h",
        "siphash.h",
        "utf8tab.h",
        "xmlrole.h",
        "xmltok.h",
        "xmltok_impl.c",
        "xmltok_impl.h",
        "xmltok_ns.c",
    ],
    includes = [
        ".",
    ],
    deps = [
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Confusingly, I did not need to specify the moved target names in expat's `cc_library`.  I'm not sure how bazel knows to run all of the `mv_file` targets first before building the `expat` target, but it seems to work.  And I was unable to set the `mv_file` target names as deps to the `cc_library`, but maybe there is a way around that to ensure actions are properly specified in terms of their dependencies.